# Postgres filtering data with a time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres

```
 | ID | TIME                |
 |  1 | 2018-01-01 01:01:00 |
 |  2 | 2018-01-01 01:02:00 |
 |  3 | 2018-01-01 01:03:00 |
 |  . | ........            |
 | 61 | 2018-01-01 02:01:00 |
 | 62 | 2018-01-01 02:02:00 |
```

I need to query all `ID` where `TIME` starts from `01:01:00`, ends on `02:02:00`, with `1 hour timestep`. So, it will be resulted in `1` and `61`

Simply saying, each `result` = `previous result` + `1 hour step`

Ideas?

**EDIT**

Don't suggest truncate or comparison with given dates. The query should be universal, allowing to use not only hours as a step, but also minutes.

Comment: What are the types of columns ?

Comment: @SumitMahamuni Time is TIMESTAMP

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 61 is 02:01:00. So, I got 01:01:00 and 02:01:00 (plus 1 hour)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I put dots to show continuity. Simply saying, I need each result = previous result + 1 hour step

Comment: What is the input to the query? `01:01:00`? How many results should the query get in general? Always 2?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Input is start_time, end_time and time_step. This one is just an example, I need to understand the query structure

Answer (score -1):

To filter your desired rows, join with a table that contains exactly the desired timestamps. You can get such a table with the table function `generate_series`:

```
SELECT times FROM generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 01:01:00',
                                  TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 02:01:00',
                                  '1 hour') times;
        times        
---------------------
 2018-01-01 01:01:00
 2018-01-01 02:01:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: What if I need up to 2018-01-01 23:00:00 with 1 hour step? This data is just example

Comment: Then you use different arguments to `generate_series`. I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score -1):

You can check If there isn't any record in same hour with smaller minute, you can select it.

The query to select first records of the hours:

```
select * from date_table dhour 
where 
not exists 
(select 1 from date_table dothers 
where 
date_part('hour', dothers.timestamp) = date_part('hour', dhour.timestamp)   
and  dothers.timestamp < dhour.timestamp 
)
```

Comment: No subquery, please

Comment: Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Subqueries are slower, isn't it?

Comment: In many cases a statement that uses a subquery can be executed more efficiently if you rewrite it as a join. I have one other solution in my mind, please check the execution plan. select min(date_part('hour', dhour.timestamp) )
from date_table dhour group by 
date_part('hour', dhour.timestamp)